# process data in a list of tuples that resides in a list

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a tuple list in a list as follow, `sof = [[], [('ABC', '0703', '', '', '', '', '', ''), ('ABC', '0702', '', '', '', '', '', '')], [('CDF', '0702', '', '', '', '', '', ''), ('CDF', '0702', '', '', '', '', '', '')] ,  [('', '', '', '', '', '', 'XYZ', '0702')]]`

I would want to process data in that list to save it in a dictionary while skipping redundant duplicate  data as dic = { 'ABC' :0703 , 'CDF': 0702 , 'XYZ' : 0702  },

so far I `m using 3 inner loops to iterate through values in these tuples as below,

`for i in sof: for j in i: for k in j: print(k)`

Comment: Instead of printing, assign the values to a dictionary. Shouldn't be very difficult if you've understood how dictionaries, lists, and tuples work. Once you've made an attempt, ask a _specific_ question about your attempt if you run into a problem. Helpful links to ask good SO questions: [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), and [mre]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
sof = [
    [],
    [
        ("ABC", "0703", "", "", "", "", "", ""),
        ("ABC", "0702", "", "", "", "", "", ""),
    ],
    [
        ("CDF", "0702", "", "", "", "", "", ""),
        ("CDF", "0702", "", "", "", "", "", ""),
    ],
    [("", "", "", "", "", "", "XYZ", "0702")],
]

out = {}
for subl in sof:
    for tpl in subl:
        tpl = [t for t in tpl if t != ""]
        if len(tpl) == 2:
            out[tpl[0]] = tpl[1]

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{'ABC': '0702', 'CDF': '0702', 'XYZ': '0702'}
```

Comment: what I have noticed after testing ,  if there is a different date with same code , your algorithm will pick the last one, for example : if I added these tuples to the sof list : `("CDF", "0630", "", "", "", "", "", ""),
        ("CDF", "0630", "", "", "", "", "", ""),` the output will be. {'ABC': '0702', 'CDF': '0630', 'XYZ': '0702'} instead of adding two codes for different dates. {'CDF':0630 , 'CDF': 0702}.

Comment: @Alani Yes, Python dictionary can hold only unique keys. Which value do you want to keep?

Comment: ahaa a unique key, I would keep the 'CDF': 0702 in case there`re two values, in that case other codes might also have different values.

Comment: @Alani Is there some rule why do you want to keep 0702? Because the value is first one?

Comment: `if subl[1] == '0706':`
            `out[subl[0]] = subl[1]` I added this rule to take in only the date I want, thank you man for bringing this to my attention,

Answer (score 1):

Adapting Andrej Kesely solution to use the Walrus operator in a dictionary comprehension

```
out = {p[0]:p[1] for subl in sof for tpl in subl if (p:=[t for t in tpl if t != ""])}
# out:
# {'ABC': '0702', 'CDF': '0702', 'XYZ': '0702'}
```

Comment: thanks you, gotta have a a look on your code.